# What is the grammar behind いないてえ?

Tags: grammar

This is a sentence from a tale I'm having trouble with. It is a Tengu speaking to a boy:

> まったくおれは何の術もかけて**いないてえ**のに本気にしやがって。

I understand this sentence to mean something like 'To be honest I haven't actually granted you any skills.'

What does いないてえ stand for； what kind of verb form is this (if I am right to assume it is some negative form of the verb いる）?

Comment: Hint: There are two words hidden in 「てえ」.  One is even a verb, believe it or not.

Answer (score 6):

This sentence is perfectly Edo dialect. いないてえのに accurately means いないっていうのに or いないというのに (いない-と-いう-のに) in normal Standard language.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should focus on 「てえのに」 instead of 「いないてえ」.

I've never seen 「てえのに」 written like that, but I guess it is some sort of sound change and means 「というのに」. The most common one I've seen is 「つうのに」.

If 「術をかける」 is about granting skills, the sentence will become

> - まったくおれは: Really, I
> - 何の術もかけていない: have not granted any skills
> - てえのに: and still
> - 本気にしやがって: you're taking it seriously

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI:

The small「っ」should be added in the original sentence when writing it. (as tyam-san mentioned, but just to be clear.)

- まったくおれは何の術もかけていない**っ**てえのに本気にしやがって。

The same thing happens when using 「つうのに」which siikamiika-san mentioned.

- まったくおれは何の術もかけていない**っ**つうのに本気にしやがって。

Since the dialect is also mentioned, here's one of the ways how some people in Kansai area could say, just for fun.

- まったくおれは何の術もかけてへんいうてんのに本気にしよって。

Comment: I believe the small っ in this position is optional. But it is true that we often see small っ there, especially between だ and てえ.

Comment: Just to add my perspective, I have never heard of 「いないてえのに」in my entire life. I have only heard of them in the forms of「〜ないって」「〜だって」, etc., just to share my experience. ;)